Define a reusable type with unique attribute
I would like to create a schema that requires, within a given element:

that a given sub-element must be present at least once
that if a given sub-element is present multiple times, each occurence must use a different named attribute

the above restrictions should apply to multiple subelements, and I would like to declare this restriction only once (that is: DRY)
In practice, this is really about providing translations for sub-elements, e.g. in the following example, both title and firstline element ought to be present at least once, but only once for each given language:
<book>
  <title lang="en">The Hobbit</title>
  <title lang="de">Der kleine Hobbit</title>
  <firstline lang="en">In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit.</firstline>
  <firstline lang="fr">Dans un trou vivait un hobbit</firstline>
</book>

whereas this should be illegal, as the <title lang="en"> element is duplicate:
<book>
  <title lang="en">The Hobbit</title>
  <title lang="en">The Hobbit or There and Back Again</title>
  <firstline lang="en">In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit.</firstline>
</book>

I know that I can create a schema that uses the unique constraint like so:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="book">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:attribute name="lang" use="required" type="xs:language"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="eachLangAtMostOnce">
      <xs:selector xpath="title"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@lang"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>

This works for the title element, but I would need to duplicate the code for the firstline element. It also puts the logic to enforce uniqueness into the containing element (book).
Is it possible to create a reusable type that does what I want?

In XSD 1.1 you can do this with an assertion:
<xs:assert test="count(distinct-values(*/concat(local-name(),@lang))) = count(*)"/>

